# How do I check if a value is a `SharedArrayBuffer` view, in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arraybuffer, sharedarraybuffer

The [`ArrayBuffer.isView()` static method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer/isView) checks if it's one of the `ArrayBuffer` views, such as `TypedArray` objects or a `DataView`.

How do you check if it's a view of a `SharedArrayBuffer`?

It's been a quite long time since `SharedArrayBuffer` was introduced, yet oddly, nobody's talking about the `SharedArrayBuffer` counterpart of the `ArrayBuffer.isView` method. Or, is it that I can use `ArrayBuffer.isView` to check for `SharedArrayBuffer` views as well?

I've read [How to check if a variable is a typed array in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15251879/4510033) but this question seems to be specifically focusing on `ArrayBuffer`s, not `SharedArrayBuffer`s.

Comment: It is that you can use `ArrayBuffer.isView` method. If `ArrayBuffer.isView` should return true for any typed array, and you need a `SharedArrayBuffer.isView` method that should return true for any typed array, then you have the very same exact functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `instanceof` on the `.buffer` property of the view:

```
view.buffer instanceof SharedArrayBuffer
```

If you are not certain whether the object is a view on any buffer at all, use `ArrayBuffer.isView(view)` first.